# iOS - UITextView size.height bigger that text inside

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have create code :

```
var sampleText = "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda."

    var emptyView = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(emptyView)
    var frame = CGRect()
    frame = emptyView.frame
    frame.origin.x = 0
    frame.origin.y = 10
    frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
    emptyView.frame = frame
    var textView = UITextView()
    textView.text = sampleText
    var frameTextView = CGRect()
    frameTextView = emptyView.frame
    textView.frame = frameTextView
    textView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 12)
    textView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    emptyView.addSubview(textView)
    textView.sizeToFit()
    textView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

and when print("(textView.frame.size.height)") I got 159,5 which is much bigger that this view take on screen. Why my textView.frame is so height?